# django check if model exist and return that to views.py

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am super new to django and I have the following problem.

I have some users in my Model "User" which has an email and a username field. I created a LoginFrom in my forms.py which only accepts an email address and checks if it exist in the User database. Then I want to return to my views.py and retrieve that model and work with it.

Very simple but, I cant do this

`return email_get`

in my forms.py as it says user already exists. The only way I can get back to views.py is by changing the form email that I got.

Something like,

`email_got="found@gmail.com" 
 return email_got`

So, how can I return to forms.py by keeping the original form email. Ps, I just want to manually check if user exist in database.

Here's my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import User

class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields= ['email']

    def clean_email(self):
        email_got = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        if User.objects.filter(email=email_got).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Your email already exist")

        return email_got
```

And my views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mail      #for sending mail
from .forms import SignUpForm, LoginForm
from .models import User


def login(request):
    username = None
    form=LoginForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
         new_user = form.save()
         username = getattr(new_user, 'username')

    context = {
        "form": form,
        "username":username,
    }       

    return render(request,"login.html",context)
```

Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: is this your real code? `if User.objects.filter(email=emailAt).count() == 1:` would throw an error if it was. But then again you are not calling the function where this code lives. So can you please post your real code?

Comment: @e4c5 thats odd, I didnt get any error when I tried. The only thing missing from my forms.py is the class SignUpForm. I didnt give that as I would cause unnecessary distractions

Comment: "you are not calling the function where this code lives"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so your `isUser` "validator" does not actually run at all. I can see you are doing custom validation on the `email` field but in order for django to know that you want `isUser` function called, you must follow the naming convention/requirement of `clean_field_name(self)`. However because you are just doing a login check, you should just check if the email exists inside `login(request)`.

So your forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import User

class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields= ['email']
```

Your views.py should look like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mail      #for sending mail
from .forms import SignUpForm, LoginForm
from .models import User

def login(request):
    username = None
    form=LoginForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid(): # This part will just do the typical Django validation (no custom validation added now).
        existing_user = User.objects.filter(email=form.cleaned_data.get('email')).first()
        if existing_user: # The email provided exists in db.
            username = existing_user.username

        else: # email does not exist so do redirect
            return redirect('name_of_your_sign_up_view')


    context = {
        "form": form,
        "username":username,
    }       

    return render(request,"login.html",context)
```

Comment: Hi @Apoorv, in the views.py, you are getting the username only if the input email is new. But as it is my login page, the email is already in the database. So now, how can I show that username, after going through the validation?
btw, your existing answer really helped me in figuring few other things out. Thanks

Comment: No worries - please see my edited answer. Just to clarify, you essentially want to create a new user when the email does not exist OR retrieve the username when an email already exists in the database (User exists already)?

Comment: The second one. Retrieve the username if the given email exist. If it doesn't then ignore or send them to the SignUpView. @Apoorv

Comment: Oh i see that makes more sense - i will update my answer when i get home

Comment: I tried your code but its not working. I found 2 problems. 
1st, except ValidationError doesn't run. 
2nd and might be the cause of 1st error is, when the form.save() fails, `form.cleaned_data.get('email') ` gives me **None**

Comment: Please see my edited answer - now that I understand your aims, i have completely removed the custom validation and `form.save()` because you are not adding anything into the database but only checking if the email exists in the database.

Comment: Mistakes: `new_user` ? You are accessing to `first().username` but may be first returns None.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fix. I also came up with a hack myself. When the is_valid() was failing, as there was no more cleaned_data availabe, I just used `form.data['email']` to get the email and then do the model query.